# Target the same child with two differents parent class

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Since few days I'm using SASS to write my css files. 
I have two different parents class but this two parents have the same children classes. So I want to build my SCSS tree of this CSS code :

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#header-g {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 300;
    width: 100%;
}

#header .l-header-top, #header-g .l-header-top {
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-top: 5px solid #474747;
    background-color: #f0f1f3;

    font-size: 16px;
}
```

I tried this but I think I forget something :

```
    #header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;

    &#header-g {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 300;
        width: 100%;

        .l-header-top {
            height: 55px;
            line-height: 50px;
            border-top: 5px solid #474747;
            background-color: #f0f1f3;

            font-size: 16px;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, if you are using `&` it means that they are in the same element and in a single element there is only 1 ID. You should use a `class` in that situation.

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;

    &#header-g {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 300;
        width: 100%;
```

but it should be something like this. `#header` and `#header-gestion` are you ID parents while they have the same children which are `.l-header-top`.

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    .l-header-top {
       height: 55px;
       line-height: 50px;
       border-top: 5px solid #474747;
       background-color: #f0f1f3;

       font-size: 16px;
    }
}

#header-g {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 300;
    width: 100%;
    .l-header-top {
       height: 55px;
       line-height: 50px;
       border-top: 5px solid #474747;
       background-color: #f0f1f3;

       font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```

Or you use `&` in this way which is based on BEM Methodology in class naming conventions. You can check this link: [BEM — Block Element Modifier Methodology](http://getbem.com/)

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    &-g {
       position: fixed;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       z-index: 300;
       width: 100%;
    }
}


#header,
#header-g {
    .l-header-top {
       height: 55px;
       line-height: 50px;
       border-top: 5px solid #474747;
       background-color: #f0f1f3;
       font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```

Comment: [DRY principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). So why not using good old fashion CSS `#header .l-header-top, #header-g .l-header-top `

Comment: he is using SCSS, and in that case, that would be the output once its build

Comment: I don't use SCSS, so I can't judge it, but can't normal CSS and SCSS be combined in one file? While repeating yourself is asking for failure. If you want to change the color, you need to change two values... You will always forget one...

Comment: They can but since you are using the SCSS much better if you do it in SCSS to structure and organize the code and readable too. Once SCSS is built, your CSS file would be minified, if you wanted to minify or not. I am using `gulp` to minify or build the CSS from SCSS file.

Comment: I do understand that, but still, if there will be more lines between the two items, you won't recognize that they should both be the same. I personally would definitely prefer to write this piece in normal CSS...

Comment: You have a point so I have updated my answer which is something similar to your perspective but in SCSS way but would be in the same output.

Comment: Thanks @boang3000 the BEM method works ! Like this I can continue my tree of childrens after .l-header-top

Comment: Glad It could help you. Cheers!

Comment: Nice, always good to provides multiple solutions. One works better for you, one other works better for some one else. +1

Comment: Thanks @LinkinTED. Glad to help :)